# Is it possible for another user to see `export SECRET="..."`?

Tags: bash

I know that if I am running a command in bash then another user can see the arguments using many different ways. So `SomeCommand $PASSWORD` is a bad idea. I assume the same applies if I do

```
env PASSWORD="SECRET" SomeCommand PASSWORD
```

where SomeCommand now reads the environment variable inside it, say with `os.environ["PASSWORD"]` in python. Though the password is now available for a shorter duration: it's the command line arg to `env` which runs SomeCommand (with PASSWORD in the environment, so someone watching `/proc` will see `env PASSWORD="SECRET" SomeCommand PASSWORD` . Note the `/proc/PID/environ` is readable by root only and as `env` is usually short lived, this is safer, but still leaks its arguments).

However, does the same apply if I use `export` e.g. `export PASSWORD="SECRET"; SomeCommand PASSWORD` since `export` is a bash builtin (i.e. it will not leak what was exported, say via `proc`)?

Comment: If you type that in at the console, it will be entered in your `.bash_history` file, which others could potentially have access to.

Comment: Yes... that I am taking into account. The home directory is private.

Comment: `ps` won't show it.  However, it would be visible in `/proc/PID/environ` to root user.

Comment: It looks like /proc/PID/environ is read only to root. Is that standard? I don't think you can hide much from root :)

Comment: /proc/PID/environ is owned by the owner of the process, not visible to anyone else.

Comment: Did you mean to type `SomeCommand "$PASSWORD"` to pass the password on the command-line, or are you passing the name of the environment variable? In the second case, you could avoid leaving the password in your persistent variables where it would be available to other executables, by typing `MYSECRET=secret SomeCommand MYSECRET`. If you are expanding `$PASSWORD` on the command line, then it will be visible in the `/proc` filesystem

Comment: I am just passing the name. The value is looked up inside. So the shell never expands the argument, and I by pass `/proc`. My question is essentially is whether `export` also show up in `proc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> SomeCommand $PASSWORD is a bad idea

Yes. The password will show up in the command line examined by ps(1) and in /proc for the duration of SomeCommand.

> env PASSWORD="SECRET" SomeCommand PASSWORD

The SECRET will show up in `ps` and /proc for the duration of `env`; it will reside in the (private) environment for the duration of SomeCommmand. This solution is slightly (or far) better.

> Does the same apply if I use export e.g. export PASSWORD="SECRET"; SomeCommand PASSWORD since export is a bash builtin?

The fact that `export` is a bash builtin doesn't mean much. This solution is even worse, because now `PASSWORD=secret` will show up in /proc for the duration of SomeCommand (as environ var of SomeCommand), and **in your own environment forever**! Unless you unset it afterward; then, it would be the same situation as using `env`.

Perhaps you could store the password in a file owned by you and not readable by others, and SomeCommand should fetch the password from that file. Or, better, implement some mechanism to make the password unique: I mean, for example, scramble your secret with something depending on the current date/time, and make SomeCommand unscramble the secret. Even if someone (root?) reads the scrambled secret, will not be quickly able to break security.

**UPDATE after comments**: given that nobody can hide anything to [the devil named] root, then the problem is to concentrate on privacy vs *other normal users*. The file /proc/PID/environment is unreadable to them, so the environment can be considered safe. Given this, the solution

> export PASSWORD=secret; SomeCommand PASSWORD

is the best because it will write *secret* in the *safe* own environment, then launch `SomeCommand PASSWORD` which will be visible with ps(1), but will not contain the actual *secret*.

The other solution,

> env PASSWORD=secret SomeCommand PASSWORD

is pretty similar but, for a short short time, *secret* will be visible by ps(1). After that short time, the `env` and the `export` ways are equivalent. 
Using `export` will leave `PASSWORD=secret` in the current environment, while `env` will not: but it is assumed that the environment is safe, as safe is the bash history file (a file containing the last command executed).

**UPDATE after comment from rici below**: right - there is no need to use export. A simple `PASSWORD=secret SomeCommand PASSWORD` has the advantage of not being visible from ps, and neither stores the secret in the current environment. So simple... a demonstration that 3 brains are better than 2!

*Final note: scrambling the secret, as suggested above, can be defeated by root if the root user has access to the source of SomeCommand. root can still disassemble SomeCommand, if the source is unreachable. root can see all the memory of the system, if wanted. In other words, root user must be trusted...*

Comment: +1. Stupid question: `env` is an external command (not a Bash builtin). So how come `env PASSWORD="SECRET" SomeCommand PASSWORD` doesn't show the password in the command line examined by ps(1)? Is it because `env` replaces its own process with the command that it executes?

Comment: By @codeforester comment `/proc/PID/environ` is read only to root (and not sure if there's any point trying to hide from root). `unset`ing after export is okay - clean up handled. If `export`s don't exists in `/proc` then I think `export` solution is best as then the `$PASSWORD` can't be given away like in `env`. So I think how `export` behaves w.r.t. `/proc` is important.

Comment: @ruakh It does show up, except `env` is usually very short lived. I point that out in the question, say versus connecting to a db. This is why I am looking for an `export` solution.

Comment: @divbyzero: You do make that claim in your question, but I don't think it's correct. (Specifically, I can't credit your claim that `env` "forks a subprocess with SomeCommand", because that would prevent the shell from `wait`-ing for that subprocess!) I was hoping that linuxfan might have the correct explanation.

Comment: @divbyzero 1) Yes, environ is unreadable by others (apart that devil named root). 2) env is short-lived, but its environment is passed to the child process, which could not be short-lived enough - this is the point: the variable containing secret does not go away when env(1) terminates. If you trust the devil named root, export is ok and marginally better than env.

Comment: @ruakh my bad. it uses execvp https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/env.c#L157

Comment: @linuxfan maybe i am missing something, but does it matter that env's environment doesn't go away if the environment cannot be accessed by anyone without root (or someone who can chown that over to themselves). maybe i should be explicit, that i only want (or can hope) to avoid other normal users, not someone with admin privileges

Comment: @divbyzero Then it is ok. If you consider your environment "safe", env and export are quite similar. With env, only a copy of secret exists, with export two.

Comment: @linuxfan but `env` gets a `/proc` entry for it's brief lifetime which causes it to leak it's arguments, does `export` ? i think this distinction is important. This is where export being a builtin comes into play.

Comment: @divbyzero For a (very very) brief time, `env PASS=SECR cmd PASS` will show; then for the duration of cmd `cmd PASS` will show. Using export, no env phase will be there, and only `cmd PASS` will be visible. Yes you are right, export is far better. But it seems you have some control on cmd, so perhaps you can even avoid the "PASS" argument and let cmd fetch the secret from a fixed environment var, perhaps scrambled or masqueraded as innocent "CPFLAGS=terces"...

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking. I should check how `export` is implemented just in case. If you will edit your answer to include this, I will accept it - thanks!

Comment: I'd go for `PASSWORD=secret SomeCommand PASSWORD` with neither the `env` nor the  `export`. That avoids the secret showing up briefly in /proc as an argument of `env`, and it avoids having the secret permanently in the export variables.

Comment: @rici Right! While exploring different ways to solve a problem, sometimes we go so deep in them that we forget that there may be _other_ ways.

Comment: @divbyzero: Ah, thanks. Somehow I didn't realize that `execvp` would update what `ps(1)` shows, but on further reflection, it's obvious that it *must* update what `ps(1)` shows, because Bash itself must use `execvp` (or another member of that family of functions) to execute non-builtin commands, and obviously `ps(1)` doesn't just show every process as being `bash`. :-)